# Why does my recursive function keep copying same object data into an array?

Tags: php, arrays, object, recursion

Running into an odd issue with my recursive function not being able to save objects into an array property.

I created a system model that points to namespaces of nested models, based on how the data is structured from the JSON data set coming in. Please note that the purpose of this JSON mapping is the map the data sets I want. The JSON data will have a ton of extraneous datasets that I don't care to read.

Please note that items like CABINETS, SYSTEM_CONFIGURATION_DATA, etc. in the arrays are globally defined constants. It has no impact on the recursive data issue that I'm facing.

```
class SystemModel {
    public $Cabinets = [CABINETS, '\App\Models\Cabinet\Cabinet'];
    public $Configuration = [SYSTEM_CONFIGURATION_DATA, '\App\Models\JsonDataFormat\Configuration\Configuration'];

    // standalone data sets
    public $SystemInformation = [SYSTEM_INFORMATION_DATA, '\App\Models\JsonDataFormat\SystemInformation'];

    public $RandomTestValue = 0;
    public $RandomTestValue2 = [0, 34535];
    public $RandomTestValue3 = [0, 'asdf\asdfask'];
}
```

These are how the models are structured:

```
namespace App\Models\JsonDataFormat\Cabinet;

class Cabinet {
    public $Amplifiers = [AMPLIFIERS, '\App\Models\JsonDataFormat\Cabinet\Amplifier'];
    public $Data = [CABINET_DATA, '\App\Models\JsonDataFormat\Cabinet\Data'];
    public $AmplifierForwardPower = 0;
    public $AmplifierReversePower = 0;
}
```

Amplifier model:

```
namespace App\Models\JsonDataFormat\Cabinet;

class Amplifier {
    public $Id = 0;             // amplifier #
    public $Online = false;
    public $Fault = false;
    public $Model = 0;
    public $SerialNumber = 0;

    public $RtcMonth = 0;
    public $RtcDay = 0;
    public $RtcYear = 0;
    public $RtcHour = 0;
    public $RtcMinute = 0;
    public $RtcSecond = 0;
}
```

Data model:

```
namespace App\Models\JsonDataFormat\Cabinet;

class Data {
    public $CabinetId = 0;
    public $Fault = 0;
    public $CriticalFault = 0;
    public $FaultState = 0;     // this is the cabinet's fault state
    public $Pump = 0;
}
```

Configuration Model:

```
namespace App\Models\JsonDataFormat\Configuration;

class Configuration {
    public $SensorWarningLimits = [SENSOR_WARNING_LIMITS, '\App\Models\JsonDataFormat\Configuration\SensorWarningLimits'];

    public $Customer = 'Customer';
}
```

System Info Model:

```
namespace App\Models\JsonDataFormat;

class SystemInformation {
    // placeholder
}
```

Sensor Warning Limits Model:

```
class SensorWarningLimits {
    public $CabinetAirTemp = [0 , 100];
    public $CabinetFlow = [0 , 100];
}
```

Below is the class that parses the JSON data, and maps the JSON data to my system model.

The data stored in `$this->decoded_json_data` is the following:

```
{
    "Cabinets": 
        [
            [0] => {
                "Id": 0,
                "Amplifiers": [
                    [0] => {
                        "Id": 0,
                        "BankIndex": 0,
                        "CabinetId": 0,
                        "RfMuteMode": 0,
                        "Online": 1,
                        "RtcSynced": false
                    }
                    [1] => {
                        "Id": 1,
                        "BankIndex": 0,
                        "CabinetId": 0,
                        "RfMuteMode": 0,
                        "Online": 0,
                        "RtcSynced": false
                    }
                    [2] => {
                        "Id": 2,
                        "BankIndex": 0,
                        "CabinetId": 0,
                        "RfMuteMode": 0,
                        "Online": 1,
                        "RtcSynced": true
                    }
                    [3] => {
                        "Id": 3,
                        "BankIndex": 0,
                        "CabinetId": 0,
                        "RfMuteMode": 0,
                        "Online": 1,
                        "RtcSynced": false
                    }
                ],
                "Data": {
                    "CabinetId": 0,
                    "Status": 4294967295,
                    "SwitchStatus": 3490543248342,
                    "Fault": 0,
                    "CriticalFault": 0,
                    "FaultStatus": 1920,
                    "Pump": 0
                },
                "AmplifierForwardPower": 200,
                "AmplifierReversePower": 10
                },
            [1] => {
                "Id": 1,
                "Amplifiers": [
                    [0] => {
                        "Id": 0,
                        "BankIndex": 0,
                        "CabinetId": 1,
                        "RfMuteMode": 0,
                        "Online": 1,
                        "RtcSynced": false
                    }
                    [1] => {
                        "Id": 1,
                        "BankIndex": 0,
                        "CabinetId": 1,
                        "RfMuteMode": 0,
                        "Online": 0,
                        "RtcSynced": false
                    }
                    [2] => {
                        "Id": 2,
                        "BankIndex": 0,
                        "CabinetId": 1,
                        "RfMuteMode": 0,
                        "Online": 0,
                        "RtcSynced": true
                    }
                    [3] => {
                        "Id": 3,
                        "BankIndex": 0,
                        "CabinetId": 1,
                        "RfMuteMode": 0,
                        "Online": 0,
                        "RtcSynced": false
                    }
                ]
                "Data": {
                    "CabinetId": 1,
                    "Status": 429342425,
                    "SwitchStatus": 34423480,
                    "Fault": 0,
                    "CriticalFault": 0,
                    "FaultStatus": 34231,
                    "Pump": 0
                },
                "AmplifierForwardPower": 100,
                "AmplifierReversePower": 20
            }
        ]
    "Configuration": {
        "Version": 2,
        "Pumps": 2,
        "AcMainVoltage": 170,
        "Customer": "MrCustomerTest",
        "SensorWarningLimits": {
            "CabinetAirFlow": [34, 489],
            "CabinetFlow": [0, 100]
        }
    }
}
```

```
class JsonParser {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->mapper = new \JsonMapper(); // this is the NetReserch JsonMapper package class
        $this->SystemModel = new SystemModel();
        $this->FetchAllModelClasses($this->SystemModel); // instantiates and compiles object models into an array, with its namespace paths as the key
    }

    private function FetchAllModelClasses($model) {
        $model_name = '\\' . get_class($model);
        $this->ArrayOfAllModelClasses[$model_name] = $model;
        foreach ($model as $property => $property_data) {
            // filter the property values (aka $property_data here)
            // if there's an array, see if there's any string with backslashes
            if (VerifyDataArrayContainsFolderPathString($property_data)) {
                $nested_model_path = $property_data[1];
                $new_model = new $nested_model_path;
                $this->FetchAllModelClasses($new_model);
            }
        }
        return;
    }

    public function Mapper() {
        if (!empty($this->decoded_json_data)) {
            $mapped_data = new \stdClass();
            $a = $this->RecursiveJsonMapping($mapped_data, $this->SystemModel, $this->decoded_json_data);
        }
        return;
    }

private function RecursiveJsonMapping($mapped_data, $model, $decoded_json_data, $depth = 0, $current_json_model_name = null) {
        // break up model between properties with and without array data
        $properties_no_array_data = $this->ListPropertiesInModel($model, false);
        $properties_have_array_data = $this->ListPropertiesInModel($model, true);
        $is_this_a_child_model = empty($properties_have_array_data) ? true : false;

        // gets the class name for the current model, which includes namespace path
        $associative_class_name = '\\' . get_class($model);

        $a = explode('\\', $associative_class_name);
        $current_json_model_name = is_null($current_json_model_name) ? $a[(sizeof($a) - 1)] : $current_json_model_name;

        // first populate any data in the current model that does not have an array that contains folder paths
        if (!empty($properties_no_array_data)) {
            // at depth 0, just set properties to mapped_data
            if ($depth == 0) {
                foreach ($properties_no_array_data as $k => $property_name) {
                    $value = (property_exists($decoded_json_data, $property_name)) ? $decoded_json_data->$property_name : $model->$property_name;
                    $mapped_data->{$property_name} = $value;
                }
            }
            // populate your datasets
            else {
                $model_properties_with_no_folder_path_arrays_only = StripModelOfPropertiesWithArraysThatContainFolderPathStrings($this->ArrayOfAllModelClasses[$associative_class_name]);

                // you're populating the current model from JSON data, so it should most likely be an object
                if (gettype($decoded_json_data) == 'object') {
                    $model_properties_with_no_folder_path_arrays_only = StripModelOfPropertiesWithArraysThatContainFolderPathStrings($this->ArrayOfAllModelClasses[$associative_class_name]);
                    $mapped_data->$current_json_model_name = $this->mapper->map($decoded_json_data, $model_properties_with_no_folder_path_arrays_only);

                    // unset properties with array values that have folder paths in them
                    foreach ($mapped_data->$current_json_model_name as $property => $property_data)
                        if (array_search($property, $properties_have_array_data) !== false)
                            unset($mapped_data->$current_json_model_name->{$property});
                }
            }
        }
                            
        // deal with nested models in the property (any property that has an array with a folder path)
        if (!empty($properties_have_array_data)) {          
            foreach ($model as $property_name => $property_data) {
                if (array_search($property_name, $properties_have_array_data) !== false) {
                    $global_name = $property_data[0];
                    $nested_model_path = $property_data[1];
                    $nested_model = $this->ArrayOfAllModelClasses[$nested_model_path];

                    // if a property contains an array with a folder path, and that folder path points to a model with folder paths, recursive loop
                    if (VerifyModelContainsPropertiesWithFolderPathStrings($nested_model)) {
                        // if data type is array, set property in our data set as an array of data models
                        if (gettype($decoded_json_data->{$property_name}) == 'array') {
                            $nesting_of_nested_models = array();
                            for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($decoded_json_data->{$property_name}); $i++) {
                                if (!empty((array) $decoded_json_data->{$property_name}[$i])) {
                                    $new_mapped_data = new \stdClass;
                                    $nesting_of_nested_models[$i] = $this->RecursiveJsonMapping($new_mapped_data, $nested_model, $decoded_json_data->{$property_name}[$i], $depth + 1, $global_name);
                                }
                            }
                            echo "<h1>$property_name</h1><pre>" . print_r($nesting_of_nested_models, true ) . "</pre>";
                            $mapped_data->{$property_name} = $nesting_of_nested_models;
                        }                           
                        // if data type is an object, such as the Configuration data set, then properly map nested data appropriately
                        else if (gettype($decoded_json_data->{$property_name}) == 'object') {
                            $new_mapped_data = new \stdClass;
                            $a = $this->RecursiveJsonMapping($new_mapped_data, $nested_model, $decoded_json_data->$property_name, $depth + 1, $global_name);

                            foreach ($a as $new_mapped_data_property => $new_mapped_data_property_value) {
                                if ($property_name == $new_mapped_data_property)
                                    $mapped_data->{$property_name} = $new_mapped_data_property_value;
                                else 
                                    $mapped_data->{$property_name}->$new_mapped_data_property = $new_mapped_data_property_value;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        // if the property name exists in the JSON data, then map the data
                        if (property_exists($decoded_json_data, $property_name) && (gettype($decoded_json_data->{$property_name}) == 'array')) {
                            $mapped_data->{$property_name} = $this->mapper->mapArray($decoded_json_data->{$global_name}, array(), $nested_model_path);
                        }
                        else if (property_exists($decoded_json_data, $property_name) && gettype($decoded_json_data->{$property_name}) == 'object') {
                            // do a check to see if there's a fringe case of a numeric array keys, which means the data set is an array
                            if (array_keys((array) $decoded_json_data->{$property_name}) === range(0, count((array) $decoded_json_data->{$property_name}) - 1)) {
                                foreach ($decoded_json_data->{$property_name} as $k => $sub_array_data)
                                    if (gettype($sub_array_data) == 'array')
                                        $mapped_data->{$property_name}[$k] = $this->mapper->mapArray($sub_array_data, array(), $nested_model_path);
                                    else $mapped_data->{$property_name}[$k] = $this->mapper->map($decoded_json_data->{$global_name}[$k], $nested_model);
                            }
                            else 
                                $mapped_data->{$property_name} = $this->mapper->map($decoded_json_data->{$global_name}, $nested_model);
                        }
                        // if the property is not part of class model, check to see if its path is legit, else throw the exception
                        else if (is_object($nested_model)) {
                            $mapped_data->{$property_name} = $nested_model;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return $mapped_data;
    }
```

My data output SHOULD look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Cabinets] => Cabs Object
                (
                    [AmplifierForwardPower] => 200
                    [AmplifierReversePower] => 10
                )

            [Amplifiers] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Amps Object
                        (
                            [Id] => 0
                            [Online] => 1
                            [Fault] => 0
                            [Model] => 0
                            [SerialNumber] => 0
                            [RtcMonth] => 0 
                            [RtcDay] => 0
                            [RtcYear] => 0
                            [RtcHour] => 0
                            [RtcMinute] => 0
                            [RtcSecond] => 0
                        )
                    [1] => Amps Object
                        (
                            [Id] => 1
                            [Online] => 0
                            [Fault] => 0
                            [Model] => 0
                            [SerialNumber] => 0
                            [RtcMonth] => 0 
                            [RtcDay] => 0
                            [RtcYear] => 0
                            [RtcHour] => 0
                            [RtcMinute] => 0
                            [RtcSecond] => 0
                        )
                    [2] => Amps Object
                        (
                            [Id] => 2
                            [Online] => 1
                            [Fault] => 0
                            [Model] => 0
                            [SerialNumber] => 0
                            [RtcMonth] => 0 
                            [RtcDay] => 0
                            [RtcYear] => 0
                            [RtcHour] => 0
                            [RtcMinute] => 0
                            [RtcSecond] => 0
                        )
                    [3] => Amps Object
                        (
                            [Id] => 3
                            [Online] => 1
                            [Fault] => 0
                            [Model] => 0
                            [SerialNumber] => 0
                            [RtcMonth] => 0 
                            [RtcDay] => 0
                            [RtcYear] => 0
                            [RtcHour] => 0
                            [RtcMinute] => 0
                            [RtcSecond] => 0
                        )
                )
            [Data] => Data Object
                (
                    [CabinetId] => 0
                    [Fault] => 0
                    [CriticalFault] => 0
                    [FaultState] => 0
                )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Cabinets] => Cabs Object
                (
                    [AmplifierForwardPower] => 100
                    [AmplifierReversePower] => 20
                )

            [Amplifiers] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Amps Object
                        (
                            [Id] => 0
                            [Online] => 1
                            [Fault] => 1
                            [Model] => 0
                            [SerialNumber] => 0
                            [RtcMonth] => 0 
                            [RtcDay] => 0
                            [RtcYear] => 0
                            [RtcHour] => 0
                            [RtcMinute] => 0
                            [RtcSecond] => 0
                        )
                    [1] => Amps Object
                        (
                            [Id] => 1
                            [Online] => 0
                            [Fault] => 0
                            [Model] => 0
                            [SerialNumber] => 0
                            [RtcMonth] => 0 
                            [RtcDay] => 0
                            [RtcYear] => 0
                            [RtcHour] => 0
                            [RtcMinute] => 0
                            [RtcSecond] => 0
                        )
                    [2] => Amps Object
                        (
                            [Id] => 2
                            [Online] => 0
                            [Fault] => 0
                            [Model] => 0
                            [SerialNumber] => 0
                            [RtcMonth] => 0 
                            [RtcDay] => 0
                            [RtcYear] => 0
                            [RtcHour] => 0
                            [RtcMinute] => 0
                            [RtcSecond] => 0
                        )
                    [3] => Amps Object
                        (
                            [Id] => 3
                            [Online] => 0
                            [Fault] => 1
                            [Model] => 0
                            [SerialNumber] => 0
                            [RtcMonth] => 0 
                            [RtcDay] => 0
                            [RtcYear] => 0
                            [RtcHour] => 0
                            [RtcMinute] => 0
                            [RtcSecond] => 0
                        )
                )
            [Data] => Data Object
                (
                    [CabinetId] => 1
                    [Fault] => 0
                    [CriticalFault] => 0
                    [FaultState] => 0
                )
        )
    [Configuration] => Configuration Object
        (
            [SensorWarningLimits] => SensorWarningLimits Object
                (
                    [CabinetAirTemp] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 0
                            [1] => 20
                        )

                    [CabinetFlow] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 0
                            [1] => 14
                        )
                )
            [Customer] => MrCustomerTest
        )
)
```

Instead, I get my "Cabinets" property duplicated with the last object data.

Basically an array that of objects with the same datasets. I've even tried using the whole `array_push($nesting_of_nested_models, clone $a)` to still no avail. Not quite sure what is going on here.

Also, I'm not sure if it's apparent, but any property that isn't able to be mapped the JSON data, the default value of the mapped model property is used.

Comment: You're first setting `$a` to `new StdClass`, then immediately reassigning it with the recursive call. But the function doesn't return anything.

Comment: Where does the function use `$mapped_data`?

Comment: You've omitted too much of the function. Please post a [mre].

Comment: @Barmar Sorry for the late response. I've updated my code to include various models and methods that were missing. A lot of the datasets have been removed, and simplified for the sake of the example.

Comment: @Barmar Found the issue. JsonMapper requires a new instance of a model mapping for some odd reason. Fixed!